# How to use common crypto and/or calculate sha256 in swift 2 & 3

Tags: swift2, sha256, digest, commoncrypto

I am trying to make hash a password value according to sha256. I already search this but there is no info about swift 2. This solution did not worked for me

```
func sha256(data:String) -> String {
        let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var digest = [UInt8](count:Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
        CC_SHA256(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
        let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joinWithSeparator("")
    }
```

It gives error: Use of unresolved identifier CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH

Comment: In what way did it not work?

Comment: Add updates to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: If you want to hash a password use `PBKDF2` instead of a simple hash.

Comment: I use this because in server side they use sha256 if it will not problem maybe I will use PBKDF2

Comment: That is OK if security is not important on the server.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add a bridging header and add the import to it:
`#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`

Swift 3:

```
func sha256(string: String) -> Data? {
    guard let messageData = string.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8) else { return nil }
    var digestData = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    _ = digestData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {digestBytes in
        messageData.withUnsafeBytes {messageBytes in
            CC_SHA256(messageBytes, CC_LONG(messageData.count), digestBytes)
        }
    }
    return digestData
}
```

// Test

```
let shaData = sha256(string:"Here is the test string")
let shaHex =  shaData!.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
print("shaHex: \(shaHex)")
```

> shaHex: 6f5c446883a3049caf8368b4bad2d2ff045a39d467ee20a8d34d5698e649fe21

Swift 2:

```
func sha256(string string: String) -> NSData {
    let digest = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))!
    if let data :NSData = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        CC_SHA256(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length),
            UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(digest.mutableBytes))
    }
    return digest
}
```

//Test:

```
let digest = sha256(string:"Here is the test string")
print("digest: \(digest)")
```

Output:

> digest: 6f5c4468 83a3049c af8368b4 bad2d2ff 045a39d4 67ee20a8 d34d5698 e649fe21

## Example from sunsetted documentation section:

**HMAC with MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512 (Swift 3+)**

> These functions will hash either String or Data input with one of eight cryptographic hash algorithms.

The name parameter specifies the hash function name as a String
Supported functions are MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512

This example requires Common Crypto
It is necessary to have a bridging header to the project:
`#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`
Add the Security.framework to the project.

These functions takes a hash name, message to be hashed, a key and return a digest:

---

```
hashName: name of a hash function as String  
message:  message as Data  
key:      key as Data  
returns:  digest as Data
```

```
func hmac(hashName:String, message:Data, key:Data) -> Data? {
    let algos = ["SHA1":   (kCCHmacAlgSHA1,   CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH),
                 "MD5":    (kCCHmacAlgMD5,    CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH),
                 "SHA224": (kCCHmacAlgSHA224, CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH),
                 "SHA256": (kCCHmacAlgSHA256, CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH),
                 "SHA384": (kCCHmacAlgSHA384, CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH),
                 "SHA512": (kCCHmacAlgSHA512, CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH)]
    guard let (hashAlgorithm, length) = algos[hashName]  else { return nil }
    var macData = Data(count: Int(length))

    macData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {macBytes in
        message.withUnsafeBytes {messageBytes in
            key.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(hashAlgorithm),
                       keyBytes,     key.count,
                       messageBytes, message.count,
                       macBytes)
            }
        }
    }
    return macData
```

### }

```
hashName: name of a hash function as String
message:  message as String
key:      key as String
returns:  digest as Data
```

```
func hmac(hashName:String, message:String, key:String) -> Data? {
    let messageData = message.data(using:.utf8)!
    let keyData = key.data(using:.utf8)!
    return hmac(hashName:hashName, message:messageData, key:keyData)
}
```

---

```
hashName: name of a hash function as String  
message:  message as String  
key:      key as Data  
returns:  digest as Data
```

```
func hmac(hashName:String, message:String, key:Data) -> Data? {
    let messageData = message.data(using:.utf8)!
    return hmac(hashName:hashName, message:messageData, key:key)
}
```

---

// Examples

```
let clearString = "clearData0123456"
let keyString   = "keyData8901234562"
let clearData   = clearString.data(using:.utf8)!
let keyData     = keyString.data(using:.utf8)!
print("clearString: \(clearString)")
print("keyString:   \(keyString)")
print("clearData: \(clearData as NSData)")
print("keyData:   \(keyData as NSData)")

let hmacData1 = hmac(hashName:"SHA1", message:clearData, key:keyData)
print("hmacData1: \(hmacData1! as NSData)")

let hmacData2 = hmac(hashName:"SHA1", message:clearString, key:keyString)
print("hmacData2: \(hmacData2! as NSData)")

let hmacData3 = hmac(hashName:"SHA1", message:clearString, key:keyData)
print("hmacData3: \(hmacData3! as NSData)")
```

Output:

```
clearString: clearData0123456
keyString:   keyData8901234562
clearData: <636c6561 72446174 61303132 33343536>
keyData:   <6b657944 61746138 39303132 33343536 32>

hmacData1: <bb358f41 79b68c08 8e93191a da7dabbc 138f2ae6>
hmacData2: <bb358f41 79b68c08 8e93191a da7dabbc 138f2ae6>
hmacData3: <bb358f41 79b68c08 8e93191a da7dabbc 138f2ae6>
```

**MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512 (Swift 3+)**

> These functions will hash either String or Data input with one of eight cryptographic hash algorithms.

The name parameter specifies the hash function name as a String
Supported functions are MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512
a
This example requires Common Crypto
It is necessary to have a bridging header to the project:
`#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`
Add the Security.framework to the project.

---

---

This function takes a hash name and String to be hashed and returns a Data:

```
name: A name of a hash function as a String  
string: The String to be hashed  
returns: the hashed result as Data
```

```
func hash(name:String, string:String) -> Data? {
    let data = string.data(using:.utf8)!
    return hash(name:name, data:data)
}
```

Examples:

```
let clearString = "clearData0123456"
let clearData   = clearString.data(using:.utf8)!
print("clearString: \(clearString)")
print("clearData: \(clearData as NSData)")

let hashSHA256 = hash(name:"SHA256", string:clearString)
print("hashSHA256: \(hashSHA256! as NSData)")

let hashMD5 = hash(name:"MD5", data:clearData)
print("hashMD5: \(hashMD5! as NSData)")
```

Output:

```
clearString: clearData0123456
clearData: <636c6561 72446174 61303132 33343536>

hashSHA256: <aabc766b 6b357564 e41f4f91 2d494bcc bfa16924 b574abbd ba9e3e9d a0c8920a>
hashMD5: <4df665f7 b94aea69 695b0e7b baf9e9d6>
```

Comment: Should I import something because it gives error at CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH and CC_SHA256 ?

Comment: You have to add a bridging header and add `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>` to it.

Comment: What should I write the header name?

Comment: I'm on Swift 3 but this answer helped me get to my solution.  Had a bit of difficulty adding the bridging header to Xcode 8.

Comment: Added Swift 3 vesion to the answer. I have AES and PBKDF2 for Swift 3 in the docunentation beta.

Comment: Elegant and lightweight compared to other swift library-based approach. One thing is I trust CommonCrypto, and I expect it to have less problem when dealing with export compliance, at least to be safe.

For me to add bridging header, I just add a new `Objective-C` file in Swift project, if it's a first Objc file then it will ask whether or not you want to add a bridging header. Yes, then go back to remove that Objc file.

Comment: Do u know how to implement hash_hmac() function from php to swift ?