# SHA256 in React Native

Tags: react-native, sha, cryptojs

I need to calculate SHA256 hash value of many files in Android and iOS using React Native.  When files are selected by a user, my app will start calculating SHA256 for each file.

For web pages, I have been using crypto-js.  But for Andoid and iOS applications, I am concerned that performance of crypto-js may not be fast enough as a file (eg. video file) may be >400 MB.

Is there any way that I can call Android/iOS native api to calculate SHA256, instead of using crypto-js for performance sake?

Comment: Just curious to know. Why do you need to calculate SHA256 of files above 400MB in size?

Comment: This is because a video file created by iPhone can easy be more than 400MB.

Comment: You can always create a native module, i.e. [one written in Java on Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html), and on iOS accordingly. [There is code for Android right here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129311/does-every-android-phone-support-sha-256), see the answer on the bottom for a complete function.

Comment: Since May 2017 there is this package: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-sha256

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't anything built into react-native itself to natively calculate a sha-256, but there are a few options.

As @Morre pointed out, [react-native-sha256](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-sha256) is an open source project that supports calculating the sha-256 of a string using native components.

Another open source react-native project - [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) - has support for calculating the sha-256 of a file using native components, specifically the [hash](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#hashfilepath-string-algorithm-string-promisestring) function.

As @Morre has pointed out, you could write your own native code to provide the same functionality if you would prefer that option. Both of the libraries I mentioned here are open source, so the source code there can be a good reference for what the specific Android/iOS code would need to be written. There are also code examples here on StackOverflow for both [java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3103652/567493) and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35749197/567493). React-Native's [native module documentation (Android)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) and [iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) is extensive.